# Is there a way to find if an app has an interface for other apps to call

Tags: linux, interface

I have an old app with limited documentation. I would like to automate some control of this app from a program or shell script that I will write. Is there a tool or a method for finding what interfaces the app supports (if any) that can be called via another program? The target app will already be running, so controlling it via "behind-the-scene" calls is what I'm hoping it supports.

Answer (score 1):

With no information about the app itself, it's a bit hard to say. However, you can probably check if the process is holding any unix, tcp, or udp sockets open using `lsof` and `netstat`. They're documented, so look up their man pages or ask on Superuser for help with them.

So what if they have a socket open? Doesn't matter if you don't know what protocol that socket is expecting you to speak at it. If you're lucky, you might be able to look up the port number, maybe using Wikipedia's [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). `netstat` might be able to tell you directly. If you can get some idea of what is running on the socket, you might be able to try talking to it.

But maybe it will be a custom protocol listening on some random port (or worse, the same port that something more popular would use). It might be listening on a unix socket, in which case you probably don't have much information to work with except for a filename and whatever error codes you can get it to vomit back at you when you send it random data. Or maybe it hasn't even opened any control sockets because you haven't configured it to do so or given it the right command line switches.

At that point, there's not much to do but bite the bullet and start reading its code. A few places that might be useful to look at are the command line argument parser and configuration file reader. If there's a remote control function, it's probably got configuration options. You could also try running a search over the codebase for any functions or constants that are common for dealing with network connections in its language. "`socket`" is a good guess in most languages.

If it's a web app, you're in much the same boat, except that just about everything the app does is network requests on a few particular ports. Web apps usually define their API in terms of HTTP requests, so  you'll mainly be looking for code that routes these requests to different areas of the codebase.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I know very little about how internal communications work. Most of my past experience is with MS and so I have seen reference to OLE, COM, .NET, and RPC, but don't know much at all about any of them. From what I understand COM and .NET I think would be the kind of interfaces that I would be looking for if I was on MS Windows, but I don't know what kind of equivalents there are on Linux. And I wasn't thinking that COM or .NET are related to sockets or Internet Protocol. Am I right?

Comment: COM is a specific example of [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). While there are several ways to implement IPC mentioned in that list, sockets and named pipes are probably the most popular in Unix land. They're also among the easiest to detect and try to interact with, since `netstat` and `lsof` can tell you if a process is using them. [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) is a popular IPC mechanism using unix sockets, and in some ways you could consider it similar to COM. Depending on how old your app is, maybe it speaks D-Bus?

Comment: Now that I have some useful insight into the General ideas involved, please forgive me for not saying at the start what I am considering. On Windows I used a screen reader ReadPlease Plus. I have it running on Linux using Wine. I used to simply highlight and copy what I wanted to read, and ReadPlease would automatically read anything copied to the clipboard. Now I have only one extra step, but I would also like to do some filtering on the text and was wondering if there was any hope of gaining back a bit of that automation. And just wanted to learn a bit about IPC in general. So thank you all.